# What is the use of {@url} in actions.xml app action URL templates?

Tags: android, actions-on-google, app-actions

In my actions.xml file, I can provide inventory for my intent's parameters using `<entity-set>` tags. For each `<entity>`, the docs indicate that I can specify a value for either `identifier` or `url`. What's the difference between `identifier` and `url`? Why do I need a `<parameter-mapping>` tag if I use `identifier`, but not if I use `url`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key difference is that `identifier` values are URL-escaped. For example:

```
<intent name="actions.intent.SOME_INTENT">
  <parameter name="param.name">
    <entity-set-reference entitySetId="identifier_entity_set">
  </parameter>
  <fulfillment urlTemplate="https://app.com/{param_value}">
    <parameter-mapping intentParameter="param.name" urlParameter="param_value" />
  </fulfillment>
</intent>
<entity-set entitySetId="identifier_entity_set">
  <entity identifier="escaped/url/path" name="hi">
</entity-set>
```

If the user says "hi" for param.name, the resolved urlTemplate will be:
https://app.com/escaped%2Furl%2Fpath.

```
<intent name="actions.intent.SOME_INTENT">
  <parameter name="param.name">
    <entity-set-reference entitySetId="url_entity_set">
  </parameter>
</intent>
  <fulfillment urlTemplate="{@url}" />
<entity-set entitySetId="url_entity_set">
  <entity url="https://app.com/not/esacaped/url/path" name="bye">
</entity-set>
```

If the user says "bye" for param.name, the resolved urlTemplate will be:
https://app.com/not/esacaped/url/path.

Also, note that if you have `{@url}` in your urlTemplate, you shouldn't include a `<parameter-mapping>` for it; it's assumed that you have exactly one `<entity-set>` with `url` values.